Is the idea that “anything that can happen will happen” true?
There is a common adage that anything that can happen will happen. More specifically, there is an often widely held notion that given enough time, even the most unlikely of things will happen.
But how do we know this is true and how can we even define probabilities on things that have never happened? For example, I can atleast intuitively grasp the idea that even given bazillions of years, matter without guidance would not spontaneously form into an airplane.
Our intuitions in this regard are often attacked and claimed to not be reliable when it comes to large time scales. But the only evidence we have of complicated things arising on large enough time scales is through evolution, and the process by which that occurs is through small changes over time, where nothing truly complex spontaneously arises in one step. None of this actually goes against intuition.
Secondly, just because our intuition may have failed when it comes to evolution, does not imply that tons of other imagined things, such as the world trade center could form without design. Could a building like the World Trade Center even through an unguided evolutionary process form even given trillions of years?
How does one even answer this question? For example, I have a strong intuition that this kind of building cannot. The response to this might be that I can’t disprove this or that my intuition might be unreliable. But why think this? Especially since almost all of philosophy is rooted in intuition anyways?

This is similar to the question as to whether monkeys typing at a typewriter forever would eventually write the works of Shakespeare. The mathematical answer is that though it’s not impossible, it’s not necessary, since you can’t rule out a monkey hitting ‘a’ forever.

@PW_246 we have an explanation for how the monkeys can type the Shakespearean work though: by pressing the right letters. We can’t even imagine an explanation for how nature by itself can form the Empire State Building: so why think that’s possible or even very improbable?

Yes, this is a crucial point. Aristotle distinguished between what exists by nature and what exists as artifice/craft. Crafts get their mode of existence from without, like from humans. What exists by nature exists according to its own inherent principles of change. That’s just one way of thinking of it.

Taking humorous hyperbole at face value is not a good idea. The point of Murphy's 'law' is to suggest that things people do not expect to happen may still happen when they are possible, and it does so in a transparently exaggerated way.

"we have an explanation for how the monkeys can type the Shakespearean work though: by pressing the right letters. We can’t even imagine an explanation for how nature by itself can form the Empire State Building: so why think that’s possible or even very improbable?"  Sure we do, volcanic eruptions spewing molten material that solidifies into neat cubes and falls in an orderly fashion into a building shape.  That's just as likely as a monkey typing anything coherently, and just as likely as an amino acid molecule grouping and folding into a complex functional protein.

A moment's reflection should convince you that the saying is literally false. I can spend tomorrow in Grimsby and I can spend tomorrow in Cleethorpes, but that does not mean I will do either, and I cannot do both.
When you talk of the World Trade Centre forming spontaneously over time, you have to consider whether that falls under the heading of something that 'can happen'. To see that it can't, think of the steps that would be involved. Consider a tiny part of the WTC- say a cable duct in the ceiling of the 32nd floor, in which there is a Cat-3 data cable held in place with a yellow cable tie. Tell me what gradual natural process leads to that outcome?

This will happen in an infinite universe, not only with a Cat-3 data cable but with me googling what a Cat-3 data cable is.  This will not happen once, but it will happen infinitely many times. Such is the nature of infinity...

@Philomath no. You are assuming an infinite universe with infinite possibilities. If you have an infinite universe that consists only of green Lego bricks, you will not find a yellow Lego brick.

@Philomath if your infinite, perpetual universe is ours, and General relativity holds true, for example, you will not find processes immune to the effects of gravity. You will not find processes that violate the conservation of energy or momentum. The possibilities are constrained by the context.

Geen Lego bricks will slowly decay, random quantum fluctuations will from time to time accidentily assemble a yellow Lego brick. Give it enough time and it will happen. Infinite time is awfully long...

Gravity will, in fact, help a lot. Given enough mass, it will accrete to a star system, or even a galaxy (again, we may have to wait a little, but we have time...). Star systems often come with planets and a planet might develop life and life might accidently develop Lego. This is far more likely to happen than a yellow Lego brick assembling by random chance. So if you are in a hurry, this is the way to go..

@Philomath Proof?

@Syed As I wrote in my answer, this is related to the Poincare recurrence theorem. The proof of this theorem is in the Wikipedia article. Don N. Page wrote an article where he calculated the Poincar´e recurrence time for our universe as: 10^10^10^10^2.08 Planck times, millenia or whatever (sic).

@Syed There is a more accessible video that can explain it better than I can do it in this tiny comment box.

@MarcoOcram, sorry to draw your attention, but I couldn't get the at username to work before. I am a newbie here...

Our intuitions are notoriously unreliable.
A good example to help you develop an intuition for the unreliability of our intuitions, is the birthday paradox: how many students are needed for the chance of having two students sharing the same birthday to be fifty-fifty? If your answer was more than 23, your intuition was wrong.
In other words: you put 23 random people together and there is a 50 per cent chance that two of them share the same birhtday.
Your question: Is the idea that “anything that can happen will happen” true?, is related to the Poincaré recurrence theorem. It states that certain dynamical systems will, after a sufficiently long but finite time, return to a state arbitrarily close to their initial state.
People have tried to apply the theorem to our Universe and some audacious mind concluded that the recurrence time for our universe is some phenomenally large number but a finite number. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do mathematical notation here, so I just leave the link. This number reflects the time for the Universe to accidentally (that is, statistically) revert to the present state. Whether that is in days, years, or whatever, is immaterial with these large numbers. The question whether we can apply the theorem to our universe is controversial though. Some people think it cannot be applied to an open, infinite universe.
If you google this you will find some entertaining videos on this subject.
Another pointer is the Boltzman brain:

The Boltzmann brain thought experiment suggests that it might be more likely for a brain to spontaneously form in space, complete with a memory of having existed in our universe, rather than for the entire universe to come about in the manner cosmologists think it actually did.

Finally, I want to point to Lee Cronin's assembly theory. It gives an alternative path to complex structures and molecules. So, instead of waiting for the whole of possibility space to accidently align with some ordered structure, this theory offers a path that is much faster. It is far more effective to have a blob of matter circle another, much larger blob of radioactive matter, and let it cool down so that life can evolve over a few billion years to eventually build a skyscraper than to wait for the skyscraper to spontaneously (and rather miraculously) assemble in interstellar space.
Anyway, the answer seems to be yes.
